# Postgres :character with Byte sequence in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent encoding in WIN1252

Tags: excel, vba, postgresql, utf-8

I am running a macro using VBA which is trying to execute a query to the postgresql database.The code works fine when I run it on Excel 2013 (version 15.0.4649.1000 32-bit). But when I try running the same code on another machine with MS Office Professional Plus 2010, Excel version 14.0.7015.1000 (32-bit), it gives me the following error

[image: Screenshot of the exact error message]

I am not sure what is the cause of this issue and how it can be resolved. Can anyone please help.

Thanks in advance
AM

Answer (score 0):

You used the Unicode driver with Excel 2013. On the other machine, the one getting the error, you used the ANSI driver.

The database contains the utf-8 sequence `0xef 0xac 0x81` which is Unicode U+0FB1, the *ﬁ* ligature. This does not exist in the WIN1252 (latin-1-like) encoding.

If your DB contains text that isn't confined to a particular ANSI codepage, you should use the Unicode driver consistently. It is generally not useful to use the ANSI driver unless you are using legacy apps that require it.

Comment: Is it possible to change the driver of the machine which is giving the error?

Comment: @user2335580 Well, sure. Just re-create the DSN using the Unicode driver.

Comment: @user2335580 Well, was it actually the ANSI driver before?

Comment: I am not sure. I have added all possible drivers PostgreSQL Unicode , PostgreSQL Unicode x64,PostgreSQL ANSI,PostgreSQL ANSI x64 hoping it matches atleast one of the list.But no avail

Comment: @user2335580 You have to *create the DSN with the correct driver*.